# ScrollIntoView dont work properly if Scroll size is bigger than browser Window - Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I have a Div which scroll is bigger than window (see image attached below), when I do scrollIntoView (written below 2 codes both gives same behaviour ) Div1 element , it is not working properly instead it Scroll to element but in middle (see image attached below), which leading element displaying half (see image attached below) .

Note : In  main Div multiple elements are present ex : Div2 ,Div3 and tried to scroll all this element but it scrolling middle of main div  .

Please help me how to handle this scenario .

[image: attached image]

Tried Code :
Code1 : `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webElement);`

Code2 :

```
                Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                builder.MoveToElement(webElement)
                       .Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Share your HTML. . .

Comment: @GirishBellamkonda, sorry to say I cannot provide HTML as it contains confidential data .......